# What is the issue with geopdf format?

Tags: python, gdal, c++, license, c

I'd like to add the geopdf format as output of a library that I am working on. After have looking around, I have not been able to find a (c, c++, python) library that meet my license requirements  (LGPL, BSD or MIT). The only way that I found until now is GDAL compiled against libpodofo as reported [here](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html). However, it looks a little bit cumbersome:

> However, for getting the imagery, the pdftoppm utility that comes with
>   the poppler distribution must be available in the system PATH.

Do you know any alternative solution?